# Upgrade SVN server on windows, don't know how/where server exists: error "Expected FS format between '1' and '3'; found format '4'

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I am wanting to upgrade a SVN server that is on version 1.5.6. The repository is on a shared drive, and we don't know who set up the server 5 years ago, or where it is at? Everything was set up on Windows, so I can't follow other posts where suggestions were made with using linux commands. Anyways, when I run "svnadmin upgrade (repo_url)" from the command line I get the following:

Repository lock acquired.
Please wait; upgrading this repository may take some time...
svnadmin: Expected FS format between '1' and '3'; found format '4'.

We are using tortoiseSVN as the clients, and want to upgrade to the latest version, but I need to figure out how to update the svn server, and apparantly have alot to learn. Can anyone provide guidance on what I need to do to upgrade to 1.8.13?

Comment: How do you connect to your SVN repository, what URL do you use? If you invoke the repository browser on one of your working copies, it should show you that URL. This should give you a hint where the server is.

Comment: I have the url path to the repository that lives on a shared drive. Do you have advice on getting past the error message above when trying to run the svnadmin upgrade command on my repository?

Comment: I suggest you ask on the subversion users mailing list (http://subversion.apache.org/mailing-lists.html). You will probably get help there.